# Get url status code using perl

Tags: perl, web, server-side

I want to create a script that the only parameter that I will give him is url. The output of the script will be the status code of the url. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at the [LWP Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/libwww-perl/lwpcook.pod) or [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny).

Answer (score 0):

[LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP) is commonly used to make HTTP requests from Perl.

There's also the very fast [Net::Curl::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Curl::Easy), which supports parallel requests using Net::Curl::Multi.

Of course, event-based frameworks have their own clients. For example, AnyEvent has [AnyEvent::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent::HTTP). These also allow parallel requests.